# query left join mysql

Tags: mysql, relational-database, left-join, join

i need to show each of the users and if the user have not answered the exam, show a zero or "n/a" from this tables:

[image: Tables in DB]

i try with this query:

```
select u.*, ac.calificacion 
from usuarios as u, examenescontestados as ac 
where u.idAdmin=11 and u.idUsuarios=ac.idUsuarios;
```

and worked:

[image]

but i need to show each of the users and if you have not answered the exam, show a zero or "n/a" or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  usuarios.*,
  IFNULL(examenescontestados.calificacion,'n/a') AS calificacion
FROM
  usuarios
  LEFT JOIN examenescontestados
    ON usuarios.idUsuarios=examenescontestados.idUsuarios
-- WHERE something
;
```